# Azure / U-SQL / R server - column names

Tags: r, azure, u-sql

I'm using U-SQL (in VS 2017) to manipulate a bunch of data and then using this aggregated output in R-Server (all of this is occurring in Azure).

I'm able to aggregate the data and connect to it in R-server.

However, the columns don't have names.

Is there a way to output the names from the U-SQL job or something like that so that I'm not using V1, V2, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the `Outputters.Csv` outputter? Use the following argument:

```
... USING Outputters.Csv(outputHeader:true);
```

That will output the column names of the rowset as a column header row.